# If (Combox.text == "ONYX") a separate combo box items get filled using a pastebin raw (C# .NET)

Tags: c#, .net, pastebin, downloadstring

I'm trying to make it so when a  separate `Combobox.text = "ONYX"`
**Other** Combobox items will be imported using Pastebin raw.

**Example:**

```
  if (api1.Text == "ONYX")`

methods1.Items.Add(new WebClient().DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/B7nFQpQ3"));
```

I tried using an Addrange instead

```
(new WebClient().DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/B7nFQpQ3"));`
```

The add range came Out Having the whole WebClient code as an error.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to split the items by line and add those items. Try this.

```
if (api1.Text == "ONYX")
{
    var downloadedString = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/B7nFQpQ3");
    var itemsSplit = downloadedString.Split('\r');
    comboBox1.Items.AddRange(itemsSplit);
}
```

Comment: I do not believe it worked. This was the exception I caught. `System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'`